# Made Tumblr tags visible, how to style them properly?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I use [this](http://pastebin.com/sei9R4Tn) theme on my blog, and used the guide from the [How to show tags in my tumblr theme? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323880/how-to-show-tags-in-my-tumblr-theme) question here on Stack Exchange to make Tumblr tags visible, and I wanted to style them like the other information (notes, timestamp and re-blog) on the side of posts, but they show up very badly (you can see the before and after making the tags visible):

[image: before and after example]

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking, you can style `.post_tag { ... }` to style these.

If you need to select their direct parent, it's `.post_tags_inner { ... }`.

You can find others by using your browser's dev tools to inspect the page. In Chrome you can right click and click "Inspect".